# Проблема кодировки в mysql

Tags: mysql, кодировка, mysqli, phpmyadmin

в phpmyadmin у базы данных и у всех таблиц установленно сравнение utf8_unicode_ci, в файле my.ini раскоментил строчки

```
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8
```

До этого кирилица на странице выводилась вопросами. Теперь кирилица выводится в виде кодов символов:

```
\u041a\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439
```

В гугле ничего по данной проблеме не нашел, как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте флаг JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE у функции  json_encode

Дополнительную информацию  смотреть http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php  и http://php.net/manual/ru/json.constants.php

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае ответ заключается в том, что функция json_encode, как я только что узнал, преобразует кириллицу в последовательность кодов символов. Т.е. без json_encode данные из базы данных получаю корректные.

Comment: где в вашем вопросе что-нибудь сказано про json_encode?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский если бы я знал что это важно... Я думал что json_encode просто берет значения из массива и переводит их в формат json без каких либо преобразований.

Answer (score 0):

если вы видите вопросы это значит не определилась кодировка. причина может быть в том что ваш файл с исходным кодом в другой кодировке (не в той которая указана в настройке сервера). С большой долей вероятности можно предположить что настройках веб сервера у вас UTF8(юникод) а файл в CP1251(виндовс).